# How to set correct Chrome extension content_security_policy regex in manifest v3

Tags: google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I was using manifest version 2 and everything was fine, But unfortunately, version 2 is no longer after 2023. So I've decided to migrate to the version3.
I was defining `content_security_policy` as below:

```
"content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; 
  object-src 'self'"
```

and now I'm trying to set it as below

```
"content_security_policy":{
  "extension_pages" : "script-src 'self' https://ssl.google-analytics.com; 
  object-src 'self'"
}
```

But I got this error:

```
Refused to load the script 'https://ssl.google-analytics.com/ga.js' because it 
violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self'". Note 
that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: ManifestV3 doesn't allow remote scripts, so you can't do this. AFAIK there's no solution currently.

Comment: @wOxxOm Is there any way that I can do it? for example, can I use gapi locally or it's impossible too? 
What do you think about this documente?
https://github.com/google/google-api-javascript-client/blob/master/docs/start.md#supported-environments